# Nginx rewriting, including other pages?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a big problem with rewriting in Nginx.
Indeed, my website have a multiple urls rewrite and i just discovered a problem with it.

The url rewrite style are :
         for url with no parameters

```
        rewrite /booster-fin.html /booster-fin.php last;
```

and this, for url with parameters

```
    rewrite /affichage-site-([0-9]+).html /affichage.php?site=$1 last;
```

It's work perfectly but, i discover a problem
in my website :

```
domain.xx/affichage-site-3.html
```

work

but

```
    domain.xx/oezfopjezffeznefzoifo-http:/affichage-site-3.html
```

**work too !!!!**

I can put anything before **-http:/** and after http:/ I can put it any existing page of the site
so :

```
domain.xx/nginxrewritproblem-http:/index.html
```

work (it's same page that domain.xx/index.html)

It's a problem with my config or nginx ?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `^` at the beginning (and possibly a `$` at the end) of your rewrites:

```
rewrite ^/affichage-site-([0-9]+).html$ /affichage.php?site=$1 last;
```

The `^` means that the url must start with what comes next and the `$` means it must end like this. The http://regexone.com/lesson/10 for some more info.

And about your problem with `domain.xx/nginxrewritproblem-http:/index.html`: This looks like there is some bad rewrite in your nginx.conf, by default nginx is not acting like this. Check all your rewrites if they really do what you want (and not more).

Comment: Thxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx !
The problem are ^ and $

It works perfectly !